# PL SQL - Stored procedure update column if parameter is not NULL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I've written a stored procedure that updates a table.
But I would like to take into account where one or more of the parameters are NULL.
In such an instance, I don't want to update the column, I want to leave the existing value as is.

I've tried to use:

```
UPDATE
      VS_USER_T
  SET
      USR_FIRST_NAME = ISNULL(p_NewUsrFName, @p_NewUsrFName)
  WHERE
      USR_ID = lv_Num_UsrId;
```

But I get an error on the '@', I'm using Oracle 12c.

**This is the procedure call**

```
  PROCEDURE UpdateUser
     ( p_UserId             IN         VS_USER_T.USR_ID%TYPE,
       p_NewUsrFName        IN         VS_USER_T.USR_FIRST_NAME%TYPE,
       p_NewUsrLName        IN         VS_USER_T.USR_LAST_NAME%TYPE,
       p_NewUsrname         IN         VS_USER_T.USR_LOGIN%TYPE)
```

Please advise how my UPDATE statement should look like, when 'p_NewUsrname          ' can be NULL, in which case I want to leave the existing value as is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please update your code so we can understand better what does your SP look like.

Comment: Are you setting parameters as optional?

Comment: Where in the Oracle manual did you find the syntax to prefix variables with `@`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep the existing value you need to refer to the existing column value:

```
USR_FIRST_NAME = ISNULL(p_NewUsrFName, USER_FIRST_NAME)
```

or you could use:

```
USR_FIRST_NAME = CASE WHEN p_NewUsrFName is null THEN USER_FIRST_NAME ELSE NewUsrFName END
```

Comment: Oracle does not have an `ISNULL` function: `ORA-00904: "ISNULL": invalid identifier`. See [@Niall answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36175914/1509264) for some Oracle functions that do the same thing.

Comment: You may either use `NVL()` or use the more verbose but common `CASE WHEN...THEN..ELSE...END` construct

Comment: I am using `CASE WHEN...` with named query but I am getting an error `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes`

Comment: I#d checking the types of the THEN and ELSE legs. But it may be worth an explicit question.

Answer (score 4):

ISNULL() is not yet a standard Oracle function (at least in the Oracle 12c version that you say you are using).  If is of course possible to write a PL/SQL function called ISNULL() and use that.

For a standard Oracle 12c installation, try using NVL or COALESCE instead.

```
USR_FIRST_NAME = NVL(p_NewUsrFName, USR_FIRST_NAME)
  or
USR_FIRST_NAME = COALESCE(p_NewUsrFName, USR_FIRST_NAME)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a decode statement e.g.

```
update my_table t
set    username = decode(p_NewUsrname, NULL, t.username, p_NewUsrname)
where  t.id = p_UserId;
```